# Couchbase configuration not found in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, couchbase

I am trying to create a simple Spring boot application. 
When I run the application, it fails to start giving this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/couchbase/config/AbstractCouchbaseDataConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I am not using Couchbase, still it is showing this error.
My pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please add the command you use to run the application.

Comment: I am running it through eclipse itself

Comment: You should see the exact command being used in the Eclipse's console.

Comment: run a "mvn clean install" via line command, it should fix your dependencies

Answer (score 1):

To start using Couchbase you need to add a Spring Boot Starter dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-couchbase) for more details.

**Note:** you can use the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) if you're not sure which dependencies are needed.

Comment: I dont want to use couchbase. Thats why I didnt include it. But still it is showing me this error

Comment: I see. Can you find where it is being referred in the project? Run from the root directory of the project `grep -n -r "couchbase"  .`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error in one personal projects, at the test phase.
I found out the message was appearing because by mistake I had a test class using SpringBootApplication.class as the base configuration class, like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = { SpringBootApplication.class })
public class ControllerTest {
...
```

It appeared to start scanning all autoconfiguration modules , including AbstractReactiveCouchbaseDataConfiguration.
Just deleted the classes attribute, the error dissapeared and tests executed OK.